# Scaling view leads to wrong (unscaled) touch positions

Tags: android, scale, android-windowmanager

I have a `RelativeLayout` that contains a lot of sub views, e.g. a `RecyclerView` with clickable items. I add this view to the `WindowManager`.

If I scale this view, I see the side effect, that touches are handled as if the view is not scaled. It looks like this effect only happens if a view is attached to the `WindowManager`.

Can I somehow solve this?

If I scale all sub views inside my `RelativeLayout`, everything works fine as those views are not attached to the `WindowManager` directly... But this means, I must scale + translate them which is a little more work as scaling the parent view only...

Comment: Can you add your `RelativeLayout ` ?

Comment: It's a simply `RelativeLayout` nothing special about the view itself... it seems to be some special behaviour of the `WindowManager` and not a view based problem